# Single Conditional Check Affecting Multiple (or All) Columns Inside a Single Row

Tags: mysql, sql

What I'd like to accomplish, is affect multiple columns of all rows where e.g. `column1 > 5` to have their values altered or replaced.

Is there any elegant way of performing this conditional check once (assuming it is a complex statement) and using its outcome for the columns using `CASE / WHEN`?

I understand that I can perform standard filtering using `WHERE column1 > 5` and `UNION` of sorts, but I'd like to learn if there are any other options (maybe even MySQL specific) available.

Edit:

As an example:

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN Country = 'UK' THEN CustomerId
    ELSE '???' 
END AS "CustomerId",
CASE
    WHEN Country = 'UK' THEN City
    ELSE '???' 
END AS "City",
CASE
    WHEN Country = 'UK' THEN Country
    ELSE '???' 
END AS "Country"
FROM Customers
```

As you can see, I'm using `CASE WHEN Country = 'UK'` multiple times here which I'd like to avoid.

Comment: What's  your dbms? mysql or mssql? could you provide some sample data and expect result ? that really help

Comment: Can you please add some sample data and required output?

Comment: Added the example

Comment: @pangular . . . I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm using MySQL, but regardless, the problem is pretty much dialect agnostic, so I included tags which are relevant for myself

Answer (score 0):

I think the elegant solution here is to have every column affected by `column1` it's own transformation function;

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION fn_transformation_for_column2(var_column1 INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    IF (fn_condition(var_column1)) THEN
        RETURN 1;
    ELSE
        RETURN 5;
    END IF;
END;
DELIMITER ;



DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION fn_transformation_for_column3(var_column1 INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    IF (fn_condition(var_column1)) THEN
        RETURN 14;
    ELSE
        RETURN 51;
    END IF;
END;
DELIMITER ;
```

based on the shared condition (which again can be a function):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION fn_condition(var_column1 INT)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
BEGIN
    IF (var_column1 > 5) THEN
        RETURN TRUE;
    ELSE
        RETURN FALSE;
    END IF;
END;
DELIMITER ;
```

Finally:

```
SELECT
    fn_transformation_for_column2(t.column1) NewColumn2,
    fn_transformation_for_column3(t.column1) NewColumn3,
    ...
FROM table t
;
```

---

Another would be to have the same transformation function for all the columns, and have the transormation handle it based on the given columntype parameter:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION fn_transformation_for_columns(var_column1 INT, var_column_no INT)
RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    IF (var_column1 > 5) THEN
        CASE var_column_no
            WHEN 2 THEN
                RETURN 1;
            WHEN 3 THEN
                RETURN 14;
            ELSE
                RETURN 0;
        END CASE;
    ELSE
        CASE var_column_no
            WHEN 2 THEN
                RETURN 5;
            WHEN 3 THEN
                RETURN 51;
            ELSE
                RETURN 0;
        END CASE;
    END IF;
END;
DELIMITER ;
```

and then:

```
SELECT
    fn_transformation_for_columns(t.column1, 2) NewColumn2,
    fn_transformation_for_columns(t.column1, 3) NewColumn3,
    ...
FROM table t
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all`:

```
select c.customerid, c.city, c.country
from customers c
where country = 'UK'
union all
select '???', '???', '???'
from customers c
where country is null or country <> 'UK'
```

Comment: I'd like to try solving the problem without UNION

Comment: @pangular . . . In MySQL, this is the simplest solution.  There is a more elegant solution in SQL Server *but the databases are different*.